# Are there enough IPv6 addresses for every atom on the surface of the Earth?

Tags: networks

There is already [a question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/can-every-grain-of-sand-be-addressed-in-ipv6) on this site comparing the number of IPv6 addresses to the number of grains of sand on earth, but my question is different.

There is a famous quote that many in networking have heard before:

> "It isn't remotely likely that we’ll run out of IPV6 addresses at any time in the future. We could assign an IPv6 address to every atom on the surface of the Earth, and still have enough addresses left to do another 100+ earths."

Is this statement is correct?

Because [according to Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number%20of%20atoms%20in%20the%20earth), there are 1x10^50 atoms on earth.

While the total number of IPv6 addresses [equals 3.4×10^38](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

Can IPv6 accommodate the atoms of 100+ more earths?

Comment: Note the difference between the number of atoms in the Earth, and the number of atoms on the surface of the Earth.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/865/

Comment: Besides the "number of atoms" the other part is "the number of IPv6 addresses". Currently (and it is not easy to change) the "2000::/3" prefix is the only one for routable global unicast addresses. And considering the fact that even for dialup sites it is tried to assign at minimum a /64. So there are "only" 2^61 = 2.3x10^18 sites if no address space is wasted (which it is).

Comment: @eckes Actually, at the ISP I work for we've decided to give out /48s because we're basically more worried about the possible eventual size of the routing table than we are about running out of address space to allocate.

Comment: it's about 1 mole of addresses per square yard of the earth's surface (http://cnx.org/content/m12460/latest)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You misinterpreted the quote.

The number of atoms on the *surface of earth*<sup>(1)</sup> is **1.26 x 10<sup>34</sup>** and the number of atoms on *earth* [is](http://education.jlab.org/qa/mathatom_05.html) **1.33 x 10**<sup>**50**</sup> (does not concern us here).

The total number of IPV6 that we can assign is:  **3.4 x 10<sup>38</sup>**.

**3.4 x 10**<sup>**38**</sup> > **1.26 x 10**<sup>**34**</sup>.

The following is true and here is the full [quote](http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/other/4306822/IPV6-How-Many-IP-Addresses-Can-Dance-on-the-Head-of-a-Pin-) for you:

> BUT, there are 6-billion people on the planet, so if everyone was
>   assigned just one IP address, we’d run out and leave 1/3rd of the
>   world without IP addresses. So they invented IPV6, a 128-bit value,
>   which is 16-bytes long. Since they had to identify this to distinguish
>   it from 4-byte values, the 1st byte has a 1-byte value that was never
>   used in the 1st byte of the original 32-bit addresses.  So that leaves
>   2<sup>120</sup> possible IP addresses using IPV6. How big is that?  Well, several
>   web sites say there are 1.33 x 10<sup>50</sup> atoms in the earth.  That’s way
>   bigger than 2<sup>120</sup>.  But to make it come closer, I computed the number
>   of atoms on the surface of the earth.  That turns out to be 1.26 x
>   10<sup>34</sup> atoms.  2<sup>120</sup> is 1.33 x 10<sup>36</sup>, which is still bigger by 10<sup>5</sup> times.
>   **So we could assign an IPV6 address to EVERY ATOM ON THE SURFACE OF THE
>   EARTH, and still have enough addresses left to do another 100+ earths.
>   It isn’t remotely likely that we’ll run out of IPV6 addresses at any
>   time in the future.**

<sup>(1) The number of atoms on the surface = 4πr<sup>2</sup> x (1/2a)<sup>2</sup>. Planet's radius = 6378km, mean atomic radius of the common stuff averages about 100pm. Total= 1.27*10<sup>34</sup> . calculated by [paul](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/18484/paul) (see the comments).</sup>

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are distinguished by the IP version field and (optionally) a field in the encapsulating frame (e.g. Ethernet frame type), not by using magic numbers inside the address field.

Comment: Another comparison: there are currently 7 billion people on Earth (7*10^9). There are estimated to be 300 billion stars in the galaxy (3*10^11). There are estimated to be 500 billion galaxies (5*10^11). If every galaxy has 300B stars, and every star has 1 planet with 7B intelligent beings, there are enough IPv6 addresses to give each of those beings 10 devices, AND do the same for another 10,000 or so universes.

Comment: I'm extremely skeptical/"call bullshit" on the calculation for the number of atoms on the surface of the Earth.  I wonder if that's a tangent or not as it relates to this question.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Since the "surface of the earth" is not particularly well-defined. I'm sure they probably doctored the numbers to fit the point. Of course to me, if you just say 128-bit address is enough to convince me. There's certainly a buttload of address space.

Comment: @HopelessN00b their calculation is calling approximately 1 10000000000000000th of the earth as the "surface". An apple is probably more than 1 1000th skin.

Comment: Number of atoms on the surface = 4πr^2 * (1/(2a))^2. Planet's radius = 6378km, mean atomic radius of the common stuff averages about 100pm. Total: 1.27*10^34. Close enough. Surface != crust.

Comment: Assume each atom in the earth is a cube and there is no space in between atoms.
Call the length of one side of this cube x.
Using x as our unit we get.
Earth's volume = 1.33*10^50 * x^3 = 4/3*pi*r^3
=> r = 3.166*10^16 * x
Earth's surface = 4*pi*r^2 = 1.26*10^34 * x^2

Comment: @paul That would be the case if the Earth was perfectly spherical, and would be a reasonable estimate if the earth was even reasonably spherical.  However, every valley and peak adds to the surface area, and the earth is ovoid to begin with... and 2/3 covered by water, all of which will skew the surface area higher compared to a perfect sphere, to a counter-intuitively large degree.  Add the unkownable distance between atoms to the equation, and ... while that number may be reasonable for an Earth-sized sphere, it could be many orders of magnitude off for the actual Earth.

Comment: @HopelessN00b don't nit-pick details on what is very obviously a broad analogy. It just annoys everyone.

Comment: So the argument is that the number of atoms *in a 1 atom thick layer* is ~10^34 ? Have I got that right?

Comment: As pointed out in Sandeep's [answer that should have been a comment](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/37818/35250), you've misquoted the source.  It says, correctly, that the factor is 105 times, not 10^5.